# Bitwise pack multiple numbers into a byte

Tags: .net, vb.net, bit-shift

I have 3 numbers which I am trying to pack these into a single byte (0-255).

```
Dim num0 As Integer = 6
Dim Num1 As Integer = 17
Dim Num2 As Integer = 30

Dim Packed As Integer = (num0 And &HFFFF) << 1 Or (Num1 And &HFFFF) << 16 Or Num2 And &HFFFF

Dim GotNum0 = (Packed >> 1) And &HFFFF
Dim GotNum1 = (Packed >> 16) And &HFFFF
Dim GotNum2 = Packed And &HFFFF
```

But the output is 10, 16, 20.

Can anyone help.

Comment: Yeah, that code is pretty wrong.  Fundamental issue as well,  Num0 needs at least 3 bits, Num1 needs 5 bits, Num3 needs 5 bits.  3 + 5 + 5 bits do not fit in an 8-bit byte.  Pretty unclear how you plan to solve the fundamental issue.  Well, don't do it, use a Structure.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

You cannot pack those 3 numbers into a single byte, you can pack them by using 3 bytes out from an Integer. Select with a mask a single byte from `Packed` to be used for each of yours numbers (with max value 255). Then convert `Packed` back:

```
Dim num0 As Integer = 6
Dim Num1 As Integer = 17
Dim Num2 As Integer = 30

Dim Packed As Integer = (num0 And &HFF) Or ((Num1 << 8) And &HFF00) Or ((Num2 << 16) And &HFF0000)

Dim GotNum0 = Packed And &HFF
Dim GotNum1 = (Packed And &HFF00) >> 8
Dim GotNum2 = (Packed And &HFF0000) >> 16
```

Comment: This code does not pack with bytes, it is packing with nybbles (half a byte, that is, 4 bits), with max values of 15 (not 255).  But the shift operations for Num1 and Num2 will shift their values outside of the respective masks, so after these operations GotNum1 and GotNum2 will both have a value of zero.  Changing the shift operations to 4 and 8 bits will align the nybble packing operations but will still be truncating data since the max value packable is 15; in that event GotNum1 will have a value of 1 (not 17) and GotNum2 will have a value of 14 (not 30).

Comment: While the edit to the code corrects the issues identified in it, this answer does not (and didn't originally) address the OP question, which was packing the values into a _single byte_.  As Hans points out in his comment to the original post, this is not possible given the question's wording.